# CNAME based php hosting

Tags: php, apache, wildcard, saas, cname

I have an application that lets users get a *.onemobi.net account (ex. `bob.onemobi.net`). Now what I would like to do is give the user the option of being able to use their own subdomain to point to their page (ex. `bob.hisdomain.com => bob.onemobi.net`). I have setup the server and bob.onemobi.net works as expected. I have added a CNAME entry for `bob.hisdomain.com => g.onemobi.net` (A record on my DNS server) but when I visit bob.hisdomain.com I automatically get redirected to www.onemobi.net. The default behaviour when a site does not exist is to show a page saying "Site does not exist" without any redirections.

I can't seem to be able to figure out what is causing this. I have tried looking around to see what could possibly be causing this but I'm lost as to what to search for. I'm hoping I can get some guidance from this community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redirection to `bob.onemobi.net` is lost in the DNS process. The server at the IP address `bob.onemobi.net` points to has to know what to do with `bob.hisdomain.com` (namely treat it the same as `bob.onemobi.net`) or the forwarding won't work.

Comment: I've added ServerAlias * but that doesnt seem to do anything. What do you recommend I do? I can't add a new alias everytime a new host is added as I am expecting lots of users to use this service.

Comment: Also I just added bob.hisdomain.com directly to httpd.conf and its still doing the same thing.

Comment: Looks like there was a syntax error in my httpd.conf I have it working now.